# UIHint not using EditorTemplate

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view-templates

I have a model like this:

```
public class MyModel {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CharityId { get; set; }

    [UIHint("Charities")]
    public SelectList Charities { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have an EditorTemplate called Charities.cshtml:

```
@model MyModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CharityId, Model.Charities)
```

Then in my page:

```
@model MyModel

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

However, no matter what, it doesn't render the Charities template.  I've been wracking my brain on this, and it should work.. but it's not.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

The issue is that the default Object template will not render a complex object other than itself (so called shallow dive), even if there is a UIHint.  I was under the impression that a UIHint would make it render the template, but I was apparently wrong.

The fix is to not try to let the model render itself.  That is sad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First things first `@EditoFormodel()` in your page looks bizarre. I guess you meant something else.

Now to the point: you have decorated the `Charities` property with `UIHint`. This property is of type `SelectList`. This means that the `Charities.cshtml` template should be strongly typed to `SelectList`, not to `MyModel` as you did. You could simply remove this UIHint attribute and have the following view model:

```
public class MyModel {
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int CharityId { get; set; }

    public SelectList Charities { get; set; }
}
```

and in your view:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

and then inside `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/MyModel.cshtml` have:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CharityId, Model.Charities)
```

That's the standard conventions. If you want your editor template to be called `Charities.cshtml` you could do this in your page:

```
@model MyModel
@Html.EditorForModel("Charities")
```

But usually you would have the following model:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    [UIHint("Charities")]
    public MyModel Charities { get; set; }
}
```

Now if your main view is strongly typed to `FooViewModel` you can:

```
@model FooViewModel
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Charities)
```

which will render the `Charities.cshtml` editor template.

Comment: No, I do not h ave a MyModel.cshtml.  I'm using the default Object template to render that.  I've corrected my mistyping for EditorForModel.  I have also tried to strongly type Charities.cshtml to SelectList and that did not render either.  I would think if the model type was wrong, it would simply throw.  But it's not even choosing Charities.cshtml to render in the first place.

Comment: @Mystere Man, as I said the problem with your code is that you have specified a UIHint attribute on the Charities property which is of type SelectList whereas your Charities.cshtml is strongly typed to MyModel which is inconsistent. Also you should use `Html.EditorFor(x => x.Charities)` if you strongly type your Charities.cshtml view model to SelectList if you want it to render.

Comment: If that were the case, it should throw, not fail to render.  In any case, I tried strongly typing it to SelectList and it still did not try to render, verified by setting a breakpoint in the view.  It's as if it's completely ignoring the UIHint, or something is overriding it.

Comment: @Mystere Man, did you replace `@Html.EditorForModel()` with `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Charities)`? If it still doesn't render I suspect that you have placed this `Charities.cshtml` file in some wrong folder.

Comment: I'm trying to let the model render itself, if at all possible.  It seems that the default Object template will not render a complex object even with a UIHint.

Comment: @Mystere Man, no it will not. The object template doesn't recurse into  complex sub objects as explained by Brad Wilson here: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html. It explains how you could tweak the default object template to make it work.