# Model property is not shown when using EditorForModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have mvc model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public int MyInt{ get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDateTime{ get; set; }

    [UIHint("_DropDown")]
    public DropDownListModel<object> MyDropDown { get; set; }

    public MyModel()
    {
        //initialize MyDropDown
    }
}
```

When I call `@Html.EditorForModel()` in view I'm just getting editors for `MyInt` and `MyDateTime`. I am able to add editor for `MyDropDown` using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDropDown)`.

How can I add editor for `MyDropDown` to `EditorForModel`?

Comment: What's a `DropDownListModel<T>`?  Why is it using `object`?  What *should* an editor for that type look like?

Comment: @David I've got this. It should look exactly like the one from `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDropDown)`.

Comment: But what does that render?  The documentation just says that `EditorForModel` will render "an HTML input" for each property on the model.  That's a custom property, so there's no single HTML input to map to it.  Do you have a template set up for it?  What is that template's name?  Does the framework otherwise find it when using other helper methods?

Comment: @David Yes, I have template: "_DropDown" and this template is map to this property by `[UIHint("_DropDown")]`. And using other helper method, like `EditorFor` works for this property. Why does it matter what does this template render if it works using `EditorFor`? It renders just drop down.

Comment: Just trying to know the full landscape of the framework components being used here.  What happens if you use `Html.EditorFor(model => Model)` on the entire `MyModel`?  What I *suspect* is that `EditorFor` (and, by extension, `EditorForModel`) doesn't examine into the non-primitive properties, at least not by default.  Though I don't have an environment handy to confirm that.

Comment: @David `Html.EditorFor(model => Model)` works exactluy the same as `Html.EditorForModel()`. I suspect it works only for primitive too. I'm trying to find if I can use non-primitive here.

Comment: Primitives only, according to this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234067/uihint-not-using-editortemplate

Answer (score 0):

I'll make this an answer because I *suspect* it's currently the correct approach, though as with any ASP.NET MVC answer it's likely to become incorrect in the next version...

`Html.EditorForModel()` is, as you may know, simply a helper with the same result as `Html.EditorFor(model => Model)`.  The current behavior of which, I *suspect*, is somewhat limited to primitive types on any given model.  Handy for certain, but not as robust as your model seems to need.

While `Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDropDown)` is smart enough to use the correct template as the editor, I don't believe `Html.EditorFor(model => Model)` is smart enough to use the correct template for *any given property* on the model, only the model itself.  (There could likely be very good reasons for this, and the implementation of it may have been a trade-off between that flexibility and some problems which may have arisen from that flexibility.)

I imagine the approach required at this time is to create a custom editor template for `MyModel`.  Internal to that template you can use `Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyDropDown)` which will in turn use *its* template.  I just suspect that nested custom templating has to be manual, not automatic.